# DBeaver import tool - transform expression

Tags: dbeaver

I would like to import a csv file into a PostgreSQL database. What expression should be used for the transformation to import the "YES" text values in the file as boolean values? (data type in the column is Booleran)

i tried the expression column_in_file=="YES" but it doesn't work